# WPF: Windows.Forms.Screen reporting wrong Bounds for Monitors

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and want to output the bounds and working areas of the monitors I have. The code is as follows:

```
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens.ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.Primary)) // Primary Screen comes first
{
    Console.WriteLine("Device:       " + screen.DeviceName);
    Console.WriteLine("Bounds      : " + screen.Bounds);
    Console.WriteLine("Working Area: " + screen.WorkingArea);
}
```

DISPLAY1 is my primary screen, and DISPLAY2 is my secondary. Both have the same resolution: 1920 x 1080.

The weird thing is that this code gives the following output:

Device:       \.\DISPLAY1
Bounds      : {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1046}

Device:       \.\DISPLAY2
Bounds      : {X=2400,Y=0,Width=2400,Height=1350}
Working Area: {X=2400,Y=0,Width=2400,Height=1308}

I have also changed the use of Screen.AllScreens with the Monitor class provided at: http://wpftutorial.net/ScreenResolutions.html but this still returns the same values. Any one ever encountered this issue?

Thanks

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a different DPI set on both screens.

Comment: Agree.  The DPI settings on Display2 are different.

Comment: Hi @RomanKo and Tony, you are correct. Changed the dpi setting to 100% from Control Panel > Display > Check "Let me choose one scaling for all my displays" and set the size to 100%. Apply and log out/log in! Done :)

Comment: @bonej010 Sure, that explains the discrepancy but now that HiDPI is common with the prevalence of 4K displays, you shouldn't have to expect a user to remove DPI scaling for your application to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to find Scale factor from windows application it works fine but when I am trying to get scale factor from WPF it returns wrong value.
I have same code in both application.
**scr.Bounds.Width** returns different value in WPF and Windows form

```
 internal static decimal ScalingFactor(Screen scr)
        {
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DEVMODE));
            EnumDisplaySettings(scr.DeviceName, -1, ref dm);

            var scalingFactor = Math.Round(Decimal.Divide(dm.dmPelsWidth, scr.Bounds.Width), 2);
            return scalingFactor;
        }
```

Windows Form Output:
[image: Windows Form Output]

WPF application Output:
[image: WPF application Output]